# Conceal initially ignored

Tags: vimrc, conceal

I'm just trying to get conceal working, so I've created a simple test case. I have a clean .vimrc file with only the following lines:

```
set conceallevel=2
syn match Conceal /syn/ conceal cchar=+
```

However, when I initially open this file in vim, the "syn" is not replaced with a "+" (it doesn't matter which line the cursor is on). But when I do `:source %` to reload this .vimrc, it starts working, replacing the occurrence "syn" with "+".

I have verified that this .vimrc *does* work when vim is initially opened for other things. For example, given the following .vimrc, the word "hi" is highlighted in red, while the word "syn" remains unconcealed until I type `:source %`.

```
set conceallevel=2
syn match Conceal /syn/ conceal cchar=+
hi Test ctermfg=red
match Test /hi/
```

What gives?

Comment: with your initial vimrc (when it is not working), what does `:verbose :set conceallevel?` output?

Comment: It says:

conceallevel=2
            Last set from ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First regarding your second example: The `match Test /hi/` is **not** syntax highlighting, but "match highlighting". This are two different things. The `hi` is still highlighted after you executed `:syntax off`.

Now the initial problem:

Your initial syntax-conceal definition is deleted in the process of loading the syntax definition needed for your `.vimrc`. While loading the syntax, Vim first removes all syntax definition active in the current buffer and replaces them with the filetype-specific definitions.

When you source the `.vimrc` again, the syntax-conceal is defined again and works.

If you want to conceal the word `syn` in vim files, create the file `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/vim.vim` (`$HOME/vimfiles/after/syntax/vim.vim` on Windows) and put your definition in it. The files from the `after` directory are loaded after Vim loaded its default configuration. So Vim first loads the default Vim syntax and after that loads your `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/vim.vim`.

See `:help mysyntaxfile-add`.